# What was the closest parallel to common assault prior to CJA 1988?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, legal-history

Common assault appears to have been defined by statute in the criminal Justice act 1988. How were comparable incidents prosecuted before this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Criminal Justice Act 1988 didn't "define" common assault, it made common assault and battery summary offences ([s39 Criminal Justice Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/33/section/39/enacted)).

In [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) common assault is an offence at common law, it isn't defined by statute.